# WebSocketMessageBrokerStats - how to set loggingPeriod

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

How to set loggingPeriod in WebSocketMessageBrokerStats to decrease value (default is 30')

WebSocketMessageBrokerStats is loaded by @Bean in [WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.java)

version : Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE

My current Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableScheduling
public class AppWebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/entry")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS()
                .setDisconnectDelay(10000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Solution :Add class extends DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration with @Configuration, and override Bean

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [WebSocketMessageBrokerStats javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/WebSocketMessageBrokerStats.html#setLoggingPeriod-long-):

> This class is declared as a Spring bean by the above configuration with the name "webSocketMessageBrokerStats"

So you can add this to your configuration class:

```
@Autowired
private WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    webSocketMessageBrokerStats.setLoggingPeriod(10 * 1000); // desired time in millis
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to setup the logging period *before* Spring has put the bean into service, you can use a `PostBeanProcessor`:

```
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof WebSocketMessageBrokerStats) {
                WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats = (WebSocketMessageBrokerStats) bean;
                webSocketMessageBrokerStats.setLoggingPeriod(30 * 1000); // your customization
            }
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }
    };
}
```

---

With `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats` it is not much of a difference to Toyo's way. However if you have a bean which won't let you change a setting after initialization, this way will always work.